# What types of holes $\pi_1(X)$ can detect?

Tags: algebraic-topology, intuition

I begin studying algebraic topology, and I'm wondering what type of hole $\pi_1$ can detect ? More precisely what are the limits of $\pi_1$ in the study of holes ?
I mean, $\mathbb{S}^2$ has a hole while $\pi_1(\mathbb{S}^2) = 0$ and $\mathbb{S}^1\times [0,1]$ as the same type of hole than $\mathbb{S}^1$ (through $\pi_1$) so we can have hole in every dimension through $\pi_1$...
After I know there is $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}(n)$ which give strange homology group (and I don't imagine how wierd are the homotopy groups). So I don't see what type of hole it detects and it's links with dimension if there is one (only the fact that loops in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are 1D manifold...)

Comment: What is a 'hole'? To me, a 'hole' is a space, $X$, is a map $S^n\to X$ that is not homotopic to a constant map. In which case one natural categorization of holes is by their dimension $n$. In which case, $\pi_n$ precisely measures $n$-dimensional holes.

Answer (score 2):

The first homotopy group $ \pi_1(X) $ detects whether all loops (that is the images of a circle) can be continously deformed to a point. You can do it on a sphere $S^2$ (because you can contract the loop moving it towards any chosen pole), but you cannot always do it on a  cylinder $S^1\times[0,1]$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already know that, the quetion is more about the geometric nature of the hole and not how we detect it, maybe there's not, but I have the feeling there is one...Like the invariant dim on the vector spaces. I have the feeling that : "if a loop cannot be reduced to a point then if we add a dimension to the shape then any loop can be reduced in a point" well I have to define what I mean by "we add a dimension" but here's the idea, quite wrong : take the example of $\mathbb{S}^1 \times [0,1]$ it has the same fundamental group than $\mathbb{S}^1$...

Comment: Homotopy group icannot be defined locally, and no local property will allow to tell you anything about it. it can also be shown that cartheasian product with an interval does not change the homotopy group. There are many other theorems about them, but if you ask what the homotopy is, the definision is pretty much it: they are they ways to classify the functions $f: \mathbb{S}^n \rightarrow X$ into certain equivalence classes. As far as I know, not much can be said abut relations between two spaces $X$, $Y$ by comparing their homotopy groups.